# Convert a binary number to a decimal number using Math Module

Tags: python, function, math, binary, decimal

**QUESTION**: 
Convert a binary number to a decimal number. (with math module)

**ANSWER PARAMETER**:
Use of the built-in functions found in the math module as
well as lists (remember to import the math module into your program!).

- *Resources*
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html
- http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-binary-to-decimal.htm

This where I am lost.

Without the answer parameter, I can convert to a binary to decimal
But I don't understand how to use the math module to get the same answer.

Converting binary to decimal without using math module.

```
print("Covert binary to decimal (Example: 1011 = 11)");
binary = input("Enter number in Binary Format: ");
try:
    #convert input to integer
    binary_con = int(binary)
    #convert binary to decimal
    decimal = int(binary, 2);
    #print decimal
    print(binary,"in Decimal =",decimal);
#if error print input number is not a interger(1 or 0)
except ValueError:  
   #print message input number is not binary
   print("That's not a Binary number")
```

Then what would I use to get the same result?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: First of all, do you understand the *math* behind converting from base 2 to base 10? Understanding that to the point where you can do it by hand is the key to knowing how to do it using the math module.

Comment: I do understand the math, and still don't see a use for the `math` module. This can be done with a very simple loop. The educational value of this (homework) question is a little lost on me.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I agree that `math` seems unneeded. I can see the value of doing it without `int()`, but math itself seem superfluous. Perhaps the author had `pow` in mind and forgot that there was no need to import it.

Comment: @JohnColeman you don't even need `pow()`, but I can see the idea behind it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs `pow()` allows for a 1-liner: `sum(int(d)*pow(2,i) for i,d in enumerate(s[::-1]))`

Comment: I have a two-liner (could be a one-liner, but my Python is not so good with oneliners :)): `for i in s: result = (result<<1) + int(i)`.

Comment: Thank you for the input so far, I will try and do it on paper first and try again. Still very new at python and coding in general. Hard to get my head around it. Thank you for the comments and suggestions.